# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: WP_Post + int

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi Im getting Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: WP_Post + int . I really dont know why this is happening. Im using the below filter to display link and html elements i want on excerpt. also to limit the amount of word displayed on the excerpt. However, when used $number parameter i get the error even though the value is interger .
$words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length  + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
this is the code that has the error.

so i put the the amount of word i want to display thorugh the apply filter below.

$topcontent = apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', '', 20 );

```
function custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text, $number) {
  
    $raw_excerpt = $text;

        // $countnumber = (int)($number);
        
        // echo $countnumber;
    
  
    if ( '' == $text ) {

        //Retrieve the post content. 
        $text = get_the_content('');
    
        //Delete all shortcode tags from the content. 
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
    
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    
        $allowed_tags = '<p>,<br>,<br/>,<br />,<a>,<em>,<strong>,<img>'; /*** MODIFY THIS. Add the allowed HTML tags separated by a comma.***/
        $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);
    
        $excerpt_word_count = $number; 
       /** MODIFY THIS. change the excerpt word count to any integer you like.***/

        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
    
        $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. get_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '">' . '...' . '</a>'; 
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);
    
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length  + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length && $words ) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . $excerpt_more ;
        } else {
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_wp_trim_excerpt', 10, 2);
```

I want to know why im not able to use the value i get from the apply filter parameter and how can i solve it?

Comment: `$excerpt_length` is an object of WP_Post, not a number. Therefore, you cannot add a 1 to it.

Comment: @aynber how can solve it ? i want to limit the amount of word for specific post. so that why i added the $number parameter there.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Wordpress, but you can try `strlen($excerpt_length)` and see if that works

Comment: @aynber  strlen($excerpt_length)  didnt work . because its not a string, its interger

Answer (score 0):

the line below refers to a hook not an integer value!

```
$excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count);
```

you may try:

```
//count the excerpt
$exlen = strlen( strip_tags( get_the_excerpt() ) );

$words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $exlen  + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I dont want to count the excerpt. I want to limit the amount of words in the excerpt . that why im using apply_filter() . u can see on    $excerpt_word_count = $number. is the parameter.

Comment: you ar passing `excerpt_length` to `preg_split` that cause error!

Comment: yes i know excerpt_length is causing the error. however if i use $excerpt_word_count = 50; instead $excerpt_word_count = $number; i dont get an error.  but i dont want to put the value directly inside the function. i want to put different value of number for different post.